# Searching a regex for matching Unicode chars that didn't fit several properties at a time

Tags: regex, unicode

Searching a regex for matching Unicode chars that didn't fit several properties at a time. For example, suppose I want all the characters in the searching string that are at the same time:

- "non letters uppercase" and
- "non letters lowercase" and
- "Non numbers"

  This obviously doesn't work: `/[\P{Lu}\P{Ll}\P{Nd}]/u`

  Seems I need a logical AND inside the regex, but I don't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this regex matches what you want to avoid:

```
/[\p{Lu}\p{Ll}\p{Nd}]/u
```

You can just use negate the char class with `^`:

```
/[^\p{Lu}\p{Ll}\p{Nd}]/u
```